# How to wrap text in myeclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, word-wrap, myeclipse

I am working on myeclipse 9 but I could not find any such feature of wrapping long lines.

Previously I was working on Myeclipse 7 and my friend suggested me a plugin http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/ and it worked beautifully there.

The same plugin is not getting installed on myeclipse 9. Please suggest me some plugin or if there is a feature in myeclipse 9 which I am unable to find it then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change code formatting by going

```
window --> preference --> Java --> code style --> formatter --> line wrapping
```

Comment: There is bug already logged with eclipse team https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779 and it is not resolved yet. Hence your solution is not working.

Comment: Oh I see. I am using IBM RAD 8.0.